# Generators of $ Z[x_1, x_2,\ldots , x_n] $

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Is there any characterization of n-element generators of $ Z[x_1, x_2,\ldots , x_n] $? They obviously need to be algebraically independent.

Comment: Unless you clarify what you mean by `characterization', there can be no good answer. For example, even with $\mathbb{Z}$ replaced by $\mathbb{C}$ and $n=2$, there are no good characterizations, other than saying there is an automorphism taking given two generators to the new set. I suppose you are aware of the Jacobian conjecture.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the Jacobian conjecture.